# Url rewrite multilnguage site

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, multilingual

I have a multilanguage site and my urls are like:
`index.php?lang=it`, `exmple.php?lang=en`, `example2.php?lang=it` and so on. I'd like to rewrite them like this:

```
index.php?lang=it => /it/index.html
example.php?lang=en => /en/example.html
```

I'd like to make a generic rule with a regex and not manually rewrite each url.

I hope I was clear.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the question is: "how can I do?"

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.+)\.php\?lang=([a-z]{2})(&|\ )
RewrteRule ^ /%2/%1.html? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.+)\.html$ /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: sir, can you explain that rewrite conditions & rules.

Comment: The first condition matches the request sent by the browser, looks for the URI from the question, groups the name of the php file (but not the extension) and the 2 letter lang value, then redirects the brwoser to /en/asdasdas.html. The second rule internally rewrites the /en/adsfssg.html back to the php file with the lang query string